# Faster Insert/Update or delete operation in mysql engine InnoDB

Tags: mysql

I have Four tables with in which two parent and two child with same structure and using InnoDB engine, and some condtions like where person_id in('1','2') I have to move selected records from one table to another tables and i have selected records upto 20 millions and it's take too much time moving

**Below table are just example and real table have very large structure**

---

**EX:**

```
1)Table :PersonDetail

Structure :

person_id  int(5) autoincrement,
name varchar(20)

Records :
person_id |Name
         1|Ankit
         2|Anuj

2)Table :HouseDetail

Structure :

id int(5) autoincrement,
housename varchar(50),
person_id int(5)

Records :

 ID |HouseName |person_id
 45 |GhostHouse|1
 50 |newworld  |1
 58 |abc       |2
 67 |xyzx      |2
```

---

*Now if i will delete person_id 1 from PersonDetail than already exist table PersonDetail_temp(which have same structure as PersonDetail) than move record from PersonDetail to PersonDetail_temp and HouseDetail which have person_id is 1 that all records need to move in HouseDetail_temp(which have  person_id =1)*

I already make this but its take too much time to move records from one table to another table

Comment: What keys do you have on the tables?

Comment: In original table i have four keys.                                KEY `pattern` (`pattern`) varchar(20),
  KEY `pricelist` (`pricelist_id`) int(11),
  KEY `reseller` (`reseller_id`) int(10),
  KEY `status` (`status`) tinyint(1)

Comment: Make sure you add an index to person_id in your DB, doesn't have to be primary

Comment: right now i have tried and its take 17 minutes approx. and how to make possible move records within 4 to 5 minutes

Comment: You need to rethink your logic.  How are you generating the list of person id's?